# Creating an array inside an if else statement in Python

Tags: python, data-structures, queue

I have the following 4 fruits stored in an list
`fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Watermelon"]`

and I use a random number generator 'numgen' to generate a value of 1 to 5.

> The output will be something like this
>   `Apple
>   Item is available
>   Orange
>   Item is unavailable
>   Pear
>   Item is available
>   Watermelon
>   Item is available`

If the number generated is 1 or 2, it should fall under `else` which will be unavailable.

Now I want to store the fruits that fall under `else` which are **unavailable** into a list using `'unavailablefruits'`  and also `'availablefruits'` to display the available fruits at the end with a count, using something like this

```
print("The following items are unavailable")
print(unavailablefruits)
print('Number of fruits available = ' + availablefruits)
print('Percentage of fruits available = " + percent)
```

I also wish to display the percentage of fruits available with `'percent'` to achieve something like this at the end

**Output:**

```
Apple
Item is available

Orange
Item is unavailable

Pear
Item is available

Watermelon
Item is available

The following items are unavailable:
Orange

Number of fruits available = 3
Percentage of fruits available = 75.0
```

I need some help because I don't know how to store them in a list and give it a name. Any suggestions?

**Revised code v2**

```
import random

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.container = []

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.container)

    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self) == 0

    def enqueue(self, item):
        self.container.append(item)

    def dequeue(self):
        return self.container.pop(0)

    def peek(self) :
        return self.container[0]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.container)

fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Watermelon"]
#unavailable_fruits = [f for f in fruits if random.randint(1, 5) in (1, 2)]
#available_fruits = list(set(fruits) - set(unavailable_fruits))
#percent_available = (len(available_fruits)/len(fruits)) * 100
q = Queue()

temp = fruits.copy()

fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Watermelon"]
d = {fruit: random.randint(1, 5) for fruit in fruits}
unavailable = [fruit for fruit in d if d[fruit] < 3]
available = [fruit for fruit in d if d[fruit] >= 3]


for fruit in fruits:
    if random.randint(1, 5) < 3:
        unavailable.append(fruit)
    else:
        available.append(fruit)

percent_available = len(available) / (len(available) + len(unavailable)) * 100

for fruit in temp:
    q.enqueue(fruit)

    print(fruit)

    numgen = random.randint(1, 5)
    if(numgen >= 3):
        print("Item is available")
    else:
        print("Item is unavailable")

print("The following items are unavailable")
print(unavailable)
print('Number of fruits available = ' + str(available))
print('Percentage of fruits available = ' + str(percent_available))
```

**Output**

```
Apple
Item is unavailable
Orange
Item is available
Pear
Item is unavailable
Watermelon
Item is available
The following items are unavailable
['Apple', 'Watermelon', 'Apple', 'Watermelon']
Number of fruits available = ['Orange', 'Pear', 'Orange', 'Pear']
Percentage of fruits available = 50.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use lists to store the available and unavailable fruits:

```
fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Watermelon"]

available = []
unavailable = []

for fruit in fruits:
    if random.randint(1, 5) < 3:
        unavailable.append(fruit)
    else:
        available.append(fruit)
```

If you would like to keep the count for each fruit you might use a dictionary:

```
d = {fruit: random.randint(1, 5) for fruit in fruits}
unavailable = [fruit for fruit in d if d[fruit] < 3]
available = [fruit for fruit in d if d[fruit] >= 3]
```

Now d contains the fruits as keys with the count as the value. You can look up the number of each fruit like this:

```
>>> d['Apple']
5
```

The number of available and unavailable fruits is simply the length of each respective list using `len()`.

The percentage available is given by:

```
>>> len(available) / (len(available) + len(unavailable)) * 100
75.0
```

Comment: I am able to calculate the percentage but for the number of fruits available, I am still unable to do so. I have edited my post so can you take a look?

Comment: You seem to have included both methods that I've shown above, so the `available` and `unavailable` lists contain multiple entries for the same items. Use the first (non-dictionary) one if you do not need to keep the counts for each fruit, otherwise just use the dictionary solution - but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an empty list up beside where you're creating the list of fruits. Now anytime you find a fruit is unavailable, add the fruit to your list. When you're finished iterating through all the fruits, that list should contain all the unavailable fruits.

Answer (score 0):

```
fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Watermelon"]
unavailable_fruits = []
available_fruits = []
unavailable = (1, 2)
for fruit in fruits:
    numget = random.randint(1, 5)
    if numget in unavailable:
        unavailable_fruits.append(fruit)
    else:
        available_fruits.append(fruit)
percent_available = (len(available_fruits)/len(fruits)) * 100
```

Or, a really concise way, and probably more pythonic:

```
unavailable_fruits = [f for f in fruits if random.randint(1, 5) in (1, 2)]
available_fruits = list(set(fruits) - set(unavailable_fruits))
percent_available = (len(available_fruits)/len(fruits)) * 100
```